# Left hand isnt deforming even though its properly weight painted?

Tags: modeling, mesh, armature

I'm creating a really crappy video game character and I'm approaching the part where I need to animate! I'm having issues with my armature on her right hand and I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work! There is probably a really simple fix, but I'm quite new to this! Sorry once again, but I'd really love help here!

[Here is the blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10M5ij9IhJeRrNpGS0-4BNd8cQLetb2Yn).

This is what I'm talking about:

[image: Rage Inducing]

Answer (score 1):

It's not properly weight painted:

[image]

As you can see thoose are the vertices which doesn't move as expected; in the "N" panel, vertex weight tab, you can read their assignements: HandL and ArmR.

You can use the vertex group tab to remove unwanted weight (armR) and apply some weight on the desired vertex group (maybe armL.003).

In the armature modifier enable theese little two buttons to see the poses also during edit mode.

If you used some automatic weight assignement and automatic flip names, the problem came because all names should END with .L or .R (not armL.003); .l and .r are OK too, but always on the end of the name.