# Mesh does not move along with bones

Tags: rigging, rigify

I'm kind of new to this, I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiXwDxCZtOc) and everything was going fine until I tried to move the character in pose mode, FK wasn't doing anything and I don't know what's wrong

I'm using blender 2.79

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-7uITyf-_iHMQ-U5oiSZ8TdnqtNF1msP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This slider decides if IK will move the arms, or FK (and it can be animated).

[image]

Comment: That did it  but I noticed it is also moving the clothes, is it because of the weight paint?

Comment: Yes, select in edit mode the vertices that have unwanted movements and paint out their unwanted assignements. See this question for details on how to see the weights and how to delete them. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95245/left-hand-isnt-deforming-even-though-its-properly-weight-painted/95286#95286